# How to upload/replace the files on a web-application at a particular place

Tags: jenkins, automation, netsuite

We have our netsuite application hosted on Oracle cloud for which we don't have access to login and we have our code placed in Gitlab. Whenever we have code changes we place the files on Netsuite app manually as shown below.

1. First we will login to the portal - we will select a option 'customization'->'Scripting'->'Scripts'. (PFB screenshot for step 1)
   [image]
2. When we select 'Scripts' below screen will get pop-up and here we will clink on '+' symbol (PFB screenshot for step 2)
   [image]
3. A new window will pop-up asking to choose the file to upload. (PFB screenshot for step 3)
   [image]
4. when we click on upload it will upload the file to 'suits-scripts' path on the web-application. This is how we are deploying the files manually. There will be files already uploaded under 'suits-scripts' with same name as they are in GitLab. so when have any code changes we need to push those only files to get replaced at the below mentioned path of netsuite application.

If I have to gist about our requirement - 
Below is the URL where we need to upload the code changes/files using any of the automation method (script/jenkins-job/any-other).

https://netsuite.com/app/common/media/mediaitemfolders.nl?folder=-15&whence=

Can someone help us, what are all the ways we can able to perform this. Either by using any script or using jenkins or any other tools.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you just want to replace the files on your webserver?

Comment: Yes, we have a code repository hosted on gitlab. After every change those particular should only need to be replaced on netsuite (web-application) at a particular place.
Any leads - would be appreciated @Xenobiologist

Comment: How do you access your webserver? Normally, you should create a Jenkins-Job or biuld-script with e.g. ant or whatever tool, do run automatically after your condition is true (you changed something). Access to a webserver depends on the operating system your client and sever is running.

Comment: At present we are replacing them manually - as a process we are maintaining the code on GitLab. Once after any changes we are replacing them on the web-application manually. So we wanted to automate this process either by using a script or jenkins job or any which means. Web-application is hosted on Oracle cloud and we don't have access to that server and even won't be getting it. To automate this we have a provisioning of Linux and Windows both, but we are not having any idea how to achieve this.

Comment: Could you describe how you manually update the files? Are you using a tool like WinSCP and copy the files with that? Are you using a web-interface of your cloud-server? What is it exactly what you want to automate?

Comment: Edited the content in my post @Xenobiologist

Comment: I do not know something about oracle netsuite. But I would recommend having a look at some kind of API for the upload. Something like this: https://blog.prolecto.com/2018/02/11/learn-how-to-upload-files-to-netsuite-via-generic-web-pages/ or this https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nsupload-org.netsuite-upload . The last solution would be automating the clicking via Autoit or selenium.